# Problems with from import in python 2.7 ( from think like a computer scientist tutorial)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial for python](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch03.html). I'm doing the exercises for chapter 3. On exercise 4 I'm having troubles with the `from import_test import *` part:

```
~ from import_test import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "pyshell#3", line 1, in <module>

   from import_test import *

File "import_test.py", line 1

Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the syntax I keep getting in return and I'm not sure what it's trying to tell me.

This is everything inside import_test.py

`Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
 ~def cat_n_times(s, n):
    print s * n`

The errors I get don't make any sense to me because i just started writing code. and i don't know how to use this site yet so thanks for putting up with my troubles.

I think I did copy the shell output into the file. i"m gonna try to fix that and see if it works. Thanks again everybody for the help.

So that didn't work I keep getting the same syntax error. Is the syntax arrow pointing to the version of python i'm using?

Comment: what are the contents of "import_test.py" as you have it?  Without the file contents, it will be impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: it looks like `import_test.py` contains the output from running the python prompt...?

Comment: @EmanYalpsid why don't you add that information to the question above, rather than just in the comments?  Think about what will make things easiest and quickest for other people to help you.

Comment: You definitely seem to have copied the shell output when you copy pasted the code into your file

Comment: I think that Padraic may be on to something...

Comment: the carat you see shows the location of the syntax error...are you sure that you didn't copy the shell out put into the file?

Comment: remove everything before `def`  including the `~` that is the shell output you have in there

Comment: yeaaaah this fixed my problems thanks Padraic

Comment: no prob, you're welcome. Keep that shell output in the shell and you will be fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're having trouble understanding the difference between a file containing python code and the shell. When you're at the shell and you type

```
from import_test import *
```

What you're essentially saying is that you want to take the entire contents of `import_test.py` and load them into your program so that you can use any function definitions, etc. contained in the `import_test.py` file in your program.

Thus, `import_test.py` needs to consist entirely of valid python code. The contents of `import_test.py` *should* exclusively be

```
def cat_n_times(s, n):
    print s * n
```

Because you have a bunch of extra junk in `import_test.py` that is not valid python code, you are getting a syntax error. This happens when the shell tries to load the contents of the file and it encounters a syntax error, meaning that you have invalid code (in this case, copied junk) in your file.

Once you have successfully loaded the `cat_n_times()` function in to your shell through the correctly implemented import, you should be able to call the function from the shell.

```
~ cat_n_times("a", 25)
```

This will print out "a", concatenated 25 times in a row. This is kind of a silly behavior to demonstrate to beginners in python, since idiosyncratic operator overloading isn't exactly a building block of Python, but that's another story...